# nothing happens when clicking button to call javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

The following code is supposed to display a confirmation box. if the user clicks the ok button, the current time is supposed to be displayed. But for some reason when I test the button by clicking on it nothing happens. I need a fresh pair of eyes to tell me what I'm missing as to why this code isn't working. Thank you for your help:

```
<script>
function confirmationDemo() {
    var ok = confirm("Click OK to show the time, \n or click Cancel to close this window \n         
without doing anything.");
    var now = new Date();
    var hour;
    var minute;
    if (now.getHours() < 12) {
        hour = now.getHours();
    } else {
        hour = now.getHours() - 12;
    }
    if (now.getMinutes() < 10) {
        minute = "0" + now.getMinutes();
    } else {
        minute = now.getMinutes();
    }
    if (ok == true && now.getHours() < 12) {
        document.getElementById("confirmationDemoReturn").innerHTML = "The time is: " + hour +
            ":" + minute + " am.";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("confirmationDemoReturn").innerHTML = "The time is: " + hour +
            ":" + minute + " pm.";
    }
}
</script>

Try it: &nbsp; <input type="button" value = "Confirmation Box" onClick =   
"confirmationDemo();">
<p id="confirmationDemoReturn"></p>
```

Comment: Check developer's console.

Comment: `without doing anything` must be on the same line than the rest of the confirmation text.

Comment: Everything is fine except this broken line problem.

Comment: Even with the broken line problem, this code does not work in JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be too simple, the text within the confirmation is not properly concatenated.    Hence it was not working.

```
 var ok = confirm("Click OK to show the time, \n or click Cancel to close this window \n   
//--- an enter key is pressed     
without doing anything.");
```

I have tested in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmrky/2/)

Comment: @user3128313 I'm glad I was able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not set events in HTML but in JS. HTML is there for structure, not for interaction. However, if you want to use this method, you have to add the following meta tag in the header of you document:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
```

However, I recommend adding the event in JavaScript like this:

```
var button = document.getElementById('btn');
button.onclick = confirmationDemo;
```

Of course after setting an id for your input:

```
<p id="confirmationDemoReturn"></p>
```

Check out this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R5t6z/